# In Termux Qemu cannot open internet, while limbo can open it running the same virtual machine

Tags: android, qemu, virtualization, termux

I downloaded many virtual machines and used with qemu, all of them cannot run internet when running with qemu commands in termux. But
If I use Limbo emulator then internet work with no problem.

---

Hi developers,

I am above ground level in linux, but much lower than sky level.

I am learning linux using my mobile phone, running termux, and using qemu inside termux for virtualization.

I downloaded and made many virtual machines with qemu, all of them cannot run internet when running inside termux qemu and using vnc with commands like:

qemu-system-x86_64 -smp 2 -usb -device usb-ehci,id=ehci -device usb-tablet,bus=usb-bus.0 -m 4G -vnc 127.0.0.1:12 -hda /sdcard/Limbo/deb12/Debian_12.0.0_VBM_LinuxVMImages.COM.vdi -netdev user,id=vmnic0 -device e1000,netdev=vmnic0

If I use limbo with just choosing user for network and same network adapter e1000, then internet work with no problem.

[Limbo network parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq9La.jpg)

I need to use termux with qemu because with recent updates I find it better performance than the dated limbo I have.

Any one can give me the commands that limbo give internally to qemu so that it is running internet for these machines on my unrooted mobile phone.

Thanks,